# Ant Design How to display "3 Selected" in Tree Select rather than display all value selected

Tags: reactjs, antd

Basically in tree select when we select some options there will be shown the values chosen

Look at [my code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-goldstine-jnltg)

But when much data selected, the display will be larger and it's better for me to show the length of data selected than show all data selected

The expected result is `4 Selected`, `2 Selected`, `5 Selected`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `maxTagCount` and `maxTagPlaceholder` properties.

In this case, `SELECTED_THRESHOLD` is constant so it will render `+ X Selected` after more than `2` selected items.

You should make your condition more generic like depending on input width etc.

[image]

```
function Demo() {
  const [selectedArray, setSelectedArray] = useState([]);

  return (
    <TreeSelect
      value={selectedArray}
      maxTagPlaceholder={`+ ${selectedArray.length - SELECTED_THRESHOLD} Selected`}
      maxTagCount={SELECTED_THRESHOLD}
      onChange={value => setSelectedArray(value)}
      ...
    >
      <TreeNode>
        ...
      </TreeNode>
    </TreeSelect>
  );
}
```

Check the demo.

[image: Edit green-microservice-xbmtg]